# Running On Device from android studio run option (instead of react-native run-android command)

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

is there any way or framework to `Running On Device` from android studio to run option to launch the app. (instead of react-native run-android command)

I don't see any stuff like that from [React-Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html).

Update:  i got some info after my research. i am seeing there is a possibility to create/modify a [gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044347/267269) which can run the yarn commands to launch my app. will keep posted.

Comment: When you click that Play button in android studio, it will let you choose whether you want to deploy it on a simulator or a real device, but in terms of real device, you need to connect it first.

Comment: Simple, if you have created your project using `react-native init`. Just inside your react-native project, there will be an Android folder. Just open that folder in Android Studio and hit run. Sometimes you might get Gradle warnings, fix it. If the react-native JS packager does not start then start it using `react-native start` from your project root.

Comment: We are using yarn package our all dependencies. the `yarn android` which we created installing the app to device correctly. but Android studio `run` doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.

**Solution**

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Start react native packager by typing `react-native start` (it will pop-out a terminal for js-bundling)
3. In android studio "Run" your App. (In case you want to use break-points "Debug-Run" your App.)
4. You are Done.

Answer (score -1):

Just open the project on android studio and hit the play button, it should work.